# Difference between File Explorer (Windows EXplorer) and Run Command

Tags: windows, networking

Is there any difference between File Explorer and Run command in Windows system while accessing the remote location path.

```
For EG: \\hostIP\folder1
```

Answer (score -1):

I haven't used Windows for a long time (I'm just using Linux for everything) but from what I remember "Run" just opens File Explorer, so there shouldn't be any difference. But I may be wrong.